# Debug log from system call stat() is not printed

Tags: linux-kernel, stat

I want to build the 4.18.1 linux kernel and add a debug log in several places: in clone and stat system calls. I added the line `printk(KERN_INFO "syscallstat");` at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.1/source/fs/stat.c#L246 and `printk(KERN_INFO "syscallclone");` at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.1/source/kernel/fork.c#L2228

After building and installing the new kernel, there is a syscallclone print in `/var/log/messages`, but no syscallstat print. To make sure that `stat` syscall is called, I created a program that calls stat() and strace shows it: `stat("f", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}) = 0`

Comment: newstat syscall is called, not stat